# ST_union with condition

Tags: postgis

I want to merge some lines with conditions but nothing seems to done 
. Here is the query :

```
drop table if exists touches_diameter_material;
create table touches_diameter_material as select a.*,st_union(a.geom,b.geom) 
as fusion from pipe a, pipe b where a.id > b.id and  a.material = b.material 
and a.diameter = b.diameter   and st_touches(a.geom,b.geom)
```

if you know how to do it I'll be pleased to get some help.

Comment: what conditions exactly? and "nothing seems to done"? what are you referring to?

Comment: Nomraly when I execute st_union the number of lines of the resulting table shoud be less than the one before union yet I still have the same number of records you see what I mean. Like the union wasn't executed or he didn't take in consideration the where clauses I put

Comment: im surprised the query doesnt throw an error that you are not using a group by with the st_union function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ST_Union`, you need a `GROUP BY` statement, otherwise everything will be combined and you will receive a single record only.

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.material,
    a.diameter,
    st_union(a.geom,b.geom) as fusion
FROM pipe a, pipe b
WHERE a.id > b.id
AND  a.material = b.material 
AND a.diameter = b.diameter
AND st_touches(a.geom,b.geom)
GROUP by a.id, a.material, a.diameter
```